Air Gap Came Loose on Sink. How Do I Put It Back On?
I'm just a renter, but my landlord has yet to respond to my concern, and usually they just tell me to fix whatever is wrong on my own.
I was cleaning this morning and seem to have scrubbed my sink too much around my air gap, because whenever I ran my dishwasher, I learned (unfortunately) the function of this device. The silver air gap is entirely removable, and I can pick it up and set it down, not just loose around the gasket.
I don't know how to put it back on the sink assembly so that I can run my dishwasher and ensure that I don't flood the cabinet it sits in and get water on the electrical outlet under the sink. Could someone direct me to a reliable tutorial please?
Pictures of air gap and under the sink: https://imgur.com/a/ofzG0WX

Do the two parts click together? If not you probably get to replace it entirely.

That's what confounds me, it does not. It just sort of rests on top of the sink. I think at some point it was glued or a part of the sink altogether, but the adhesive holding it in gave up when I was trying to remove some calcium around it. I thought maybe that there would be a part where you'd poke it through the hole and screw it in from below, but that doesn't look like how it's built?

push the large green part in the last picture upward through the hole and take another topside picture

These are usually a single piece or two pieces that thread or snap together. It's not likely you damaged it by cleaning, but it could have had a crack that split when bumped.
